# Passing MSForms.Control as argument in Word VBA

Tags: vba, arguments, ms-word

I have to set ActiveX control tab order in MS Word using VBA. So here is the basic code:

```
Private Sub radioFull_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, _
                              ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 9 Then
        radioIntern.Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

Problem is I have an active Restrict Editing Protection on the document set by password. Thus after starting protection, while pressing a tab on any control, it deny to functioning saying that I have a protection on the document.

So, during execution of the above function, I first have to un-protect the document, moving tab to next field and then re-protect by the following function:

```
Private Sub ToggleProtect()
    If ActiveDocument.ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
        ActiveDocument.Unprotect Password:="password"
    Else
        ActiveDocument.Protect Password:="password", NoReset:=True, _
                               Type:=wdAllowOnlyFormFields, _
                               UseIRM:=False, EnforceStyleLock:=False
    End If        
End Sub

Private Sub radioFull_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, _
                              ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 9 Then
        ToggleProtect
        radioIntern.Activate
        ToggleProtect
    End If
End Sub
```

It works well. So I intend to shorten the main code a little bit more by something like this:

```
Private Sub radioFull_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, _
                              ByVal Shift As Integer)
    tabOrder(KeyCode, controlName)
End Sub
```

and the tabOrder function in this case like the follwoing:

```
Public Sub tabOrder(K as integer,t as string)
    If KeyCode = K Then
        ToggleProtect
        t.Activate
        ToggleProtect
    End If
End Sub
```

But I am not familiar on VBA function argument. So please tell me how to pass the argument or write the function correctly so that I can maintain tab order in MS Word form?

Comment: Which function are you asking help for with the arguments?  Also, in your `tabOrder` sub, you can't "activate" `t` because it's a `String` and not a control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the MS Forms controls are derived from `MSForms.Control` VBA is apparently unable to "cast" them to this data type. It can work with the general type, however. The trick is to declare the procedure argument as data type `Variant`.

While I was at it, I made another small optimization to the code by declaring an object variable of type `Word.Document` for passing the document to `ToggleProtect`. While it's unlikely, it is theoretically possible that the user will change documents during code execution, making the `ActiveDocument` a different one than that which triggered the code. So if you get the target document immediately then the code will always execute on the correct document, no matter which one currently has the focus.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, _
                             ByVal Shift As Integer)
        Dim doc As Word.Document

        Set doc = Me
        tabOrder KeyCode, doc, Me.TextBox1
End Sub

Public Sub tabOrder(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, _
                    ByRef doc As Word.Document, ByRef t As Variant)

   If KeyCode = 9 Then
      ToggleProtect doc
      t.Activate
      ToggleProtect doc
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleProtect(doc As Word.Document)
    If doc.ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
        doc.Unprotect Password:="password"
    Else
        doc.Protect Password:="password", NoReset:=True, _
                               Type:=wdAllowOnlyFormFields, _
                               UseIRM:=False, EnforceStyleLock:=False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked, although I used only `t As Variant` option. As there is a least chance of changing document by user as it is a Application Form and changing document will affect on his/her own career. So I excluded the modified part of your code in order to keep file size smaller by less line of codes. Thanks again. You saved by time and labor.

Answer (score 0):

In your KeyDown event, it looks like you want to pass the KeyCode and the Control.  Therefore, the arguments you pass must match the signature of the `tabOrder` sub.  Look how KeyCode is defined and copy/paste to your `tabOrder` sub.  The second argument will be defined as Control allowing for any control to be passed.  Here is an example of what I am talking about:

```
Private Sub radioFull_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
   tabOrder KeyCode, radioFull
End Sub

Public Sub tabOrder(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByRef t As MSForms.Control)
   If KeyCode = 9 Then
      ToggleProtect
      t.Activate
      ToggleProtect
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Not working. While pressing tab key it is showing `Run-time error 13, Type  mismatch` and if press debug it takes to this line of code:`tabOrder KeyCode, radioIntern` [my objective is while in a option button (activeX control)- `radioFull`, if I press tab it takes the cursor to another option button (activeX control) named as `radioIntern` and it will continue tabbing in between all activeX controls of the document]

Comment: Take a look at the answer from @Cindy, it may be of help.